Performance difference between two operating systems: Windows Server 2022 & Windows Server 2016
We are using 32 bit VB6 application and facing slowness in our application when using windows 2022 server. When we check in task manager, our application is split into multiple processes and executed the application. This is not happening in windows 2016 server and 32 VB6 bit application does not face slowness. Both applications access same level of data in same database. How to sort out this issue?
We want the reason of the time difference. and also any suggestion on how to improve performance on Windows 2022 Server
